# External DVD burner rejects region 2 DVDs on Mac only

Tags: mac, dvd

Bought a new VicTsing USB 3 dvd burner for use on my El Capitan Mac. I put in a region 2 DVD and fired up VLC, but the drive won't read my DVD. It spun it around a number of times **and ejected it ** . **Tested the drive with the same region 2 dvd on Windows 7 and it works.**

Question: How can I get the drive to accept the disk and let me worry about having software to read it? All posts I've found don't reference the drive spitting out the disc and suggest appropriate software to read it

Comment: DVD drives have a "5 swaps & it's locked" policy. If you played 5 region 1 disks, then it's now locked to region 1 for life. Some drives have known firmware hacks to get around this, you'd have to Google to see if there's a known one for that device.

Comment: that doesn't seem to explain the different behaviour on windows

Comment: Actually it's "change the region five times" before it becomes locked to the last region that was played.  I know hardware tools exist that will reset that limit but even those can only be employed a set number of times.  Welcome to defective by design.

Comment: And it's only DVDs that are locked like that.  A Blu-Ray drive also has a set number of times the region can be changed but at least in Windows the region change count is stored in software, not hardware.  Which means if you can find the registry key for it or if you just reinstall Windows then your change count is reset.